# Apply a datetime to a file but for 1 day in the past

Tags: python, datetime, timedelta

Does anyone know how I can apply a date one day in the past as my filename? With this code, it would give me a file name of `'File09202021161235.csv'` however I would like this to output 1 day in the past.

```
 'File' + datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%m%d%Y%H%M%S''.csv')
```

I tired using `timedelta(days=1)` but then the strftime breaks? Can anyone offer any guidance?

Comment: `I tried using timedelta(days=1)`, show us what you tried. Timedeltas are definitely a part of the solution

Comment: yeah exactly, i tried `datetime.timedelta(days=1).strftime('%m%d%Y%H%M%S'.'csv')` and the strftime just stops working for me!

Comment: timedeltas are quantities that can be added or substracted from datetimes.

Comment: @MrFuppes sorry, force of habit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very simple. First of all you are  doing it wrong.

```
datetime.timedelta(days=1)
```

It's only the time for 1 days. It's not a current time. It's an interval.

The fix is you need to subtract the this 1 days time interval from current time.

```
import datetime

#Here we are subtracting the current time with 1 days time interval
past_day = datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
your_file_name = 'File' + past_day.strftime('%m%d%Y%H%M%S''.csv')
```